# Why my android spinner is transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an Android newbie...
And I have a problem with my spinners.
I have an activity with an image as background and a spinner with items (a list of years) loaded by code using an adapter.
The problem is that when the spinner is closed, it's transparent except of the text and the right down corner triangle (black).
If I set the spinner background color, the right down corner disappear and the spinner becomes very similar to a textView (too much confused for the user!).

If I change the activity style (for example "Black"), in the graphical view the spinner becomes like I want it:
lightgray and with the right down corner.

But in the runtime phase, it becomes again transparent.

[Screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/27924376@N06/8624765886/)

Why?
Suggestions?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

XML in the activity for Spinner

```
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnScan"
            android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnScan"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

Java activity code for Spinner initialization

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Years);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnYear.setAdapter(adapter);
spnYear.setSelection(spnYear.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use your `custome xml` layout file and set in Your `Adapter`

```
myfile.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textname"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#449def"         
    android:padding="5dip"/>

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.myfile, Anni2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. Only the text color is changed (before was black and now azure), but the background is transparent.

Comment: here you can set Background color also for all spinner

Comment: its just sample here need to modify by you as require

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've added android:background, but only the textual part of the spinner is colored. The part of the spinner where is the right down corner it's transparent.

Answer (score 0):

add this `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` to your spinner

Comment: But...I have some AVDs and with AVDs until Android 2.3 the spinner aspect is like I want, but since 3.0 the aspect is transparent.

Comment: which answer? none of the replies are marked as answer

Comment: @tusharnarang Massimo didn't accept any answer, but he said in the comments that my answer helped him.